# Facebook api does not upload image

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

My issue is already discussed here
[couldn't open file "" error in Facebook PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909923/couldnt-open-file-error-in-facebook-php-api)

and my php script is

```
//variables we are going to post to facebook
$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,user_photos';  //Required facebook permissions
$PicLocation = 'fb_cover_images/cover7.jpg';
$msg_body = array(
    'message' => 'I liked this pic from '. $homeurl .
     ' it is perfect for my cover photo.',
     'url' => "http://my_site.com/$PicLocation"
);

if ($fbuser){ //user is logged in to facebook, post our image
  try {
     $uploadPhoto = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $msg_body );
  } 
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //output any error
  }
}
else{
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
  array('scope'=>$fbPermissions,'return_url'=>$return_url));
  header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
}
```

If I set   `'url' => "http://my_site.com/$PicLocation"` then getting

> (#200) Permissions error

and If I set  `'url' => "@http://my_site.com/$PicLocation"` then getting

> couldn't open file "http://my_site.com/fb_cover_images/cover7.jpg"

message though if I hit `"http://my_site.com/fb_cover_images/cover7.jpg"`, I can view image and permission to folder+image is set to 777.

Please guide what I am doing wrong....
I have searched but fail.

I also tried [PHP + Facebook: how to upload photo on the wall? but same rubbish message `(#200) Permissions error`

Also [Upload Photo To Album with Facebook's Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api)
I don't know what the hell is going on with FB API.

Comment: just some tips: "publish_actions" is the only permission you need. and you don´t need 777 permissions on the folder. after all you don´t want to write something, but just read the image and put it on facebook.
and another thing: the message parameter needs to be 100% user generated. just saying.

Comment: updated `$fbPermissions = 'publish_stream,user_photos,publish_actions';  //Required facebook permissions` but same issues :(

Comment: again, publish_actions is the ONLY permission you need. you really need to check out the facebook docs about permissions. don´t use permissions "just because they work", remove all unneccessary ones.

Comment: and of course this may not solve the problem at hand, but it is a very important thing to notice.

Comment: I also tried [PHP + Facebook: how to upload photo on the wall?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407800/php-facebook-how-to-upload-photo-on-the-wall) but same rubbish message `(#200) Permissions error`

Comment: please somebody guide me.... I have already spend two days on this issue.

Comment: can somebody explain me what should be the format for `$FILE_PATH` and what actually `$args['image']` have?

Comment: I dont know what the hell is going on with the FB API..... :(

Comment: are you sure the picture is available and not behind a login or so? i just checked in one of my projects, i am using the direct url like this and it works: "https://myserver.com/myimage.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to the top of your code, after setting up Facebook:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport( true );
```

Then, change your `$msg_body` to the following:

```
$msg_body = array(
  'name' => 'I liked this pic from '. $homeurl . ' it is perfect for my cover photo.',
  'source' => "http://my_site.com/$PicLocation"
);
```

The `name` is the caption for the image, and the `source` is the URL to the file. You only need to prefix `@` to the source if you are referencing a local file.